# For each item in a list, iterate over all other items of another list, output an array - python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, iterable

I have two python lists (of nltk synsets).  For each item in the first list, I want to iterate over all items of the second list and output a value that applies a method to the first list using the items of the second list as arguments to the method.

Example:

```
l1 = [wn.synset('i.n.03'), wn.synset('need.v.03'), wn.synset('aid.n.01')]
l2 = [wn.synset('help.v.01'), wn.synset('girl.n.01')]
```

For each item in l1, I want to compute the similarity score with each item in l2, resulting in a 3x2 matrix containing similarity scores of every possible 2-way combination containing one value from l1 and one value from l2.

I could compute the first row of the matrix as follows:

```
fwrd= l1[0]
frow= np.asfarray([fwrd.path_similarity(i) for i in l2])
```

Resulting in values of frow as

```
array([        nan,  0.06666667])
```

The first value in this array is the similarity score between wn.synset('i.n.03') and wn.synset('help.v.01')
The second value is the similarity score between
wn.synset('i.n.03') and wn.synset('girl.n.01')

The second row in the array would contain similarity scores between the second item in l1 with both items in l2, etc.

I've tried a few clunky ways of getting there without any luck.  Thanks for your help.  Also, I would really like to understand *how* the code solution works, so any references would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured I'd need itertools but could not figure out which function.  A little refinement for those who may be trying to do something similar.  To get the array mentioned, I actually used: `np.asfarray([i.path_similarity(j) for i,j in itertools.product(l1,l2)]).reshape(len(l1),len(l2))`

Answer (score 0):

A nested list comprehension should provide the output you are looking for:

```
[[fwrd.path_similarity(i) for i in l2] for fwrd in l1]
```

Just pass this to `np.ndarray()`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I'd need itertools but could not figure out which function. A little refinement for those who may be trying to do something similar. To get the array mentioned, I actually used: `np.asfarray([i.path_similarity(j) for i,j in itertools.product(l1,l2)]).reshape(len(l1),len(l2))`

Comment: @RosieMB You can post an answer to your own question, it's hard to see answers in comments.